# Error in Spliting and Concatenating String

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

I am trying to make query by performing operation on String. I have a `String` named query like this:

```
2010-10-01' and '2013-10-01' and (extension='5028' or extension='00' or extension='
```

Now with the following code I am deleting last 16 characters from query string. Here is the code:

```
query=query.substring(0,query.length()-16);
```

output of this snippet is:

```
2010-10-01' and '2013-10-01' and (extension='5028' or extension='00
```

Now I want to concatenate the string with this character:

```
query=query.concat("')");
```

output of above snippet is

```
2010-10-01' and '2013-10-01' and (extension='5028' or extension='00)'
```

Whereas I need the output like this:

```
2010-10-01' and '2013-10-01' and (extension='5028' or extension='00')
```

Comment: I get the expected output when I run exactly the same lines you mentioned. Are you sure there is no other code running in between?

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using? (You only need to post the section that does what you explained here.) Also, this is technically not an error, but rather an anomaly. An error throws an exception; an anomaly does something unexpected, but does not terminate the compiler or program.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I don't get downvoted since I don't have time to check this right now but it looks to me like you're in the single-quote/double quote character vs string mess.  I'm a little surprised it compiled.  I'd try:

query=query.concat("\')");